# Command line tool to edit FAT/FAT32 attributes on Mac OS X?

Tags: command-line, fat32, attributes

Is there a command line tool to edit the FAT/FAT32 attributes (hidden, system, read-only) on Mac OS X?

The "chflags" command seems to apply specifically to HFS filesystems...

Searching the web turns up people curious about "extended attributes" but not about the three basic attributes.

Help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The [mtools](http://www.gnu.org/software/mtools/) toolkit will do what you want. Specifically the mattrib command.

```
Mtools version 3.9.11, dated May 31st, 2007
Usage: mattrib [-p] [-a|+a] [-h|+h] [-r|+r] [-s|+s] msdosfile [msdosfiles...]
```